# How to call one function in a class in the child class showing error in python?

Tags: python, class

```
 class Student:
     def __init__(self,name,a,b,c):
         self.name=name
         self.a=a
         self.b=b
         self.c=c
         def totalscore(self):
             self.score=self.a+self.b+self.c/100
             return score
 class Result:
     def __init__(self,stlist):
         self.stlist=stlist
     def grade(self):
         for i in stlist:
             x=i.totalscore()
             if(x>80):
                 print('A')
             elif(x>60 and x<80):
                 print('B')
             elif(x>40 and x<60):
                 print('c')
             else:
                 return None
 if __name__=='__main__':
     n=int(input('Enter  the input student'))
     stlist=[]
     for i in range(n):
         name=input('enter the name of student')
         a=int(input())
         b=int(input())
         c=int(input())
         stlist.append(Student(name,a,b,c))
     u=Result(stlist)
     u.grade()
```

I get a `NameError`

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-e20009ff9dd6> in <module>
     32         stlist.append(Student(name,a,b,c))
     33     u=Result(stlist)
---> 34     u.grade()`enter code here`
     35 
     36 
<ipython-input-3-e20009ff9dd6> in grade(self)
     13     def grade(self):
     14         for i in stlist:
---> 15             x=i.totalscore(score)
     16             if(x>80):
     17                 print('A')
NameError: name 'score' is not defined**
```

Comment: The traceback is pretty self-explanatory. name 'score' is not defined in the scope of your 'grade' method. Also Student.totalscore() does not accept any arguments. Not to mention the fact that you have declared totalscore as a nested function which will not allow you to access it outside your `__init__`.

Comment: I don't understand the question as asked. Where you have `x=i.totalscore(score)`, what do you think the value of `score` should be, and where should that value come from? Why?

Comment: I want to call the first function inside the class of Student in the result class for calculating the grade

Comment: One more correction: the line `for i in stlist:` in the `grade` method should be `for i in self.stlist:`. Currently this method uses the `stlist` variable from the `__main__` section not the `stlist` attribute of the `Result` class.

Answer (score 0):

The method `totalscore()` should be outside `__init__()` if you want to call it.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self,name,a,b,c):
        self.name=name
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.c=c

    def totalscore(self):
        score=self.a+self.b+self.c/100
        return score
        

class Result:
    def __init__(self,stlist):
        self.stlist=stlist
    def grade(self):
        for i in self.stlist:
            # Here you are calling the totalscore() function of Student
            x=i.totalscore()
            if(x>80):
                print('A')
            elif(x>60 and x<80):
                print('B')
            elif(x>40 and x<60):
                print('c')
            else:
                return None
```